# How to position a image absolute using JavaScript so that it doesn't move irrespective of the screen size

Tags: javascript, css

```js
var wrapper = document.createElement("div");

wrapper.innerHTML = "<img src='https://www.seoclerk.com/pics/want37749-19XWVR1460035914.png' style=\"border-radius:50%;top:22%;left:5%;position:absolute;transform:scale(.12);z-index:99;\">"

    var videoWrapper = document.createElement("div")

    videoWrapper.className = "videoWrapper"

    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')

    iframe.src =  "https://www.youtube.com/embed/2Vv-BfVoq4g" 

    videoWrapper.appendChild(iframe)

    videoWrapper.style.position = "relative"

    wrapper.appendChild(videoWrapper)
    
    document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
```

```css
.videoWrapper {
  position: relative;

  /* 16:9 */
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
}

.videoWrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  border: none;
}
```

I have this dynamically created div:

I wanted to align the wrapper.innerHTML image to the video wrapper class so that my yout.png doesn't move irrespective of what the scree size is. I have tried giving the wrapper relative postion but it doesn't work. Can somebody help on how to achieve the same.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to replicate your work?

Comment: @TreeNguyen added

Comment: I am unable to run the code snippet

Comment: But did you see any error

Comment: I can't see your code working either.

Comment: Please see now. Its working

Comment: give it position fixed https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: i tried but then the image remain fixed at a position and when scree size is increased it moves according to change in pixel